# Using a 'lookup' table in MS-ACCESS for an update query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an Access Database with a table [tblManipulate] with the following four fields populated with data:

```
[tblManipulate].[Name] 
[tblManipulate].[Description] 
[tblManipulate].[Price]
[tblManipulate].[Account code]
```

I also have an 150 entry table of descriptions called [tblDescLookup] that needs to be utilized like a lookup table in order to manipulate account codes. Example entries follow:

```
[tblDescLookup].[Description Lookup]    [tblDescLookup].[Account Code Result]
*demonstration*                         10000
*coding*                                12000
*e-mail*                                13000
```

---

What is the best way to take every record in [tblManipulate] and check the [tblManipulate].[Description] field against [tblDescLookup].[Description Lookup], assigning the account code result into the original table if a 'like' match is found?

This seems to me like one of those instances where Access is not the best tool for the job, but it is what I have been instructed to use. I would appreciate any help or insight (or alternatives!). Thank you!

Comment: It seems that for *"[tblManipulate].[Description] field against [tblDescLookup].[Description Lookup]"*, you want a `Like` comparison instead of exact match.  Is that an absolute requirement?

Comment: Yes, I do want a `Like` comparison. The individuals who populate the [tblManipulate] description fields use keywords but do not do so consistently. Some pseudo-code would like `[tblManipulate].[Account code] = if ([tblManipulate].[Description] like [tblDescLookup].[Description Lookup], [tblDescLookup].[Account Code Result], [tblManipulate].[Account code])`

Comment: Give them a form with a combo box to input `[tblManipulate].[Description]` ... then they will only input valid values and you can use exact match (good) instead of `Like` (not so good) for the lookup.

Comment: That is a great suggestion, I will bring that forward as a solution to reduce future problems. In the interim, I will have to use one of the loop answers provided by the other users. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it for you.

```
Dim Description As String
Dim lookupDescription As String

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SELECT * FROM tblManipulate) 

 If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
        rs.MoveFirst 'good habit

       Do Until rs.EOF = True


       Description = rs("Description")

       Dim rsLookUp As DAO.Recordset
       Set rsLookUp = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SELECT * FROM tblDescLookup) 


              If Not (rsLookUp .EOF And rsLookUp .BOF) Then
                      rsLookUp .MoveFirst 'good habit

                      Do Until rsLookUp.EOF = True

                      lookupDescription = rsLookUp("Description Lookup") 

                      If() Then    'match criteria
                       'assign value 
                      End if

                      rsLookUp.MoveNext
                      Loop

                     Else
                          MsgBox "No records in the recordset."
                      End If


              rs.MoveNext
            Loop


            Else
                MsgBox "No records in the recordset."
 End If
```

Comment: This is working great! I really appreciate you thinking through this. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. Needed to do something similar not too long ago so I thought I'd save you the trouble of figuring it out. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Oy.  You're going to need a loop here.  I would open up tblDescLookup in a recordset:

```
Set rec = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset ("Select * from tblDescLookup")
```

Then loop through each record and run the query that way:

```
Do While rec.EOF = False

    Set rec2 = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset ("Select * from rec where Description like '" & rec("Description Lookup") & "'")

    rec.MoveNext

Loop
```

Or maybe you need to make that an Update statement instead?  I can't write that off the top of my head, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
Update tblManipulate as t1
Set [Account Code] = (Select [Account Code Result] from [tblDescLookup] where [Description Lookup] = t1.[Description])
```

Comment: like with 宮本 武蔵's answer, I need to make a `like` comparison. Is there a way to use `like` rather than equal?

Comment: If i understand you correctly, you should just be able to swap out a 'like' for the = in the above SQL.  Can you provide me with an example?